# Drupal 7: How to render an individual element after it's array has been rendered?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I've been working on someoneelses code where they are rendering a form. In the .tpl file they render some individual elements as such:

```
<?php print render($form['datepicker']); ?>
```

before then rendering the remaining form elements with:

```
<?php print render($form); ?>
```

I've learnt that rendering an individual array item (like the datepicker above) will exclude it from being rendered when the whole array is called. But is there a way to exclude something and render it *after* its parent array is rendered.

Eg:

```
<?php print render($form['datepicker']); ?> //<-- Will not be rendered in render($form);
<?php print render($form); ?> 
<?php print render($form['termsAndConditions']); ?> //<-- Will be render twice, here and in render($form);
```

(The goal is to wrap the tersmAndConditions element in its own HTML after the remaining form elements have been rendered.)

Answer (score 0):

Use

> hide($form['datepicker']);

It will exclude 'datepicker' from $form but $form['datepicker'] will still exist for render

its mean you will do this by

```
hide($form['datepicker']);
print render( $form );
```

for $form['termsAndConditions'] you need to print it twice you have to store this in a variable before rendering

like your full code is be like

```
hide($form['datepicker']); // // We hide the datepicker now so that we can render them later.
print render($form['datepicker']);
$termsAndCond = $form['termsAndConditions'];
print render( $form );
print render($termsAndCond);
```

HOPE this solve you problem

THANKS